# Google won't read web pages on my Android 8.1.0 phone

Tags: google, text-to-speech

When I bring up a web page on Google assistant & say
"Hey (or Ok) Google read it" nothing happens, & in Google Go, the play button triangle is greyed out.
These apps have permission to use the microphone and I have tried making seemingly helpful changes to all the obvious settings I could find.

Comment: So your question is only about the Go edition where reading web sites does not work (neither via button nor via speech command)?

Comment: Unless Google Assistant is just Google Go in disguise, then my question is not solely about Google Go